# Объединить матрицы в трехмерную

Tags: python

подскажите как правильно будет объединить две матрица, чтобы она стала трехмерной.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import re


SIG = []
SIG_str = []
MOD = []
i = 0

SNR_start = []
S = 0
SNR = []
R = []

path = f'C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\NN\\My_dataset\\8APSK' # получаем директорию i-ой папки
os.chdir(path) # перемещаемся в директорию i-ой папки
path_files = os.listdir(path) # получаем список файлов i-ой папки

for g in range(100): # цикле от первого до последнего файла i-ой папки
     
    with open (f'C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\NN\\My_dataset\\8APSK\\{path_files[g]}') as f:
        
        S = 0
        regex = re.compile(r"_(\-?\+?\d+)dB_")
        text = path_files[g]
        S = regex.findall(text)
        R = S[0]
        SNR_start.append(R)
        
        col1 = []
        col2 = []
        col3 = []

    
        for line in f:  
            first, second, third = line.split()
            col1.append(first)
            col2.append(second)
            col3.append(third)
            
            SIG_dist = ([float(el.replace(",", ".")) for el in col2])
            SIG_mnim = ([float(el.replace(",", ".")) for el in col3])
        
        SIG.append(list(map(float, SIG_str)))   
        
        SNR = list(map(int,  SNR_start))
    MOD.append(i)
    
    i += 1 

    
print (i)
```

Мне нужно объединить SIG_mnim, и SIG_dist в одну матрицу, чтобы ёё размерность стала 3.
Т.е. у нас есть сигнал который содержит мнимую и действительную часть, сигнал 1024 отсчета, и допустим у нас 100 таких сигналов, надо объединить матрицы, и получить одну размерами (100, 2, 1024)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно вас понял, то у вас `SIG_mnim` и `SIG_dist` имеют размерность `100 на 1024` или `1024 на 100`. И вы хотите объединить это все в трехмерный массив. Если все так, то лучше конечно получить трехмерную матрицу `(2, 100, 1024)`.

Это делается очень просто:

```
SIG = np.array([SIG_mnim, SIG_dist])
```

После этого мы имеем трехмерный массив размерностью `(2, 100, 1024)`, где `SIG[0]` - матрица мнимых, а `SIG[1]` - матрица действительных частей.

Comment: А как получить массив формата (100, 2, 1024)?

Comment: прошу прощения за глупые вопросы, сам разобрался. Воспользовался np.stack с параметром axis = 1

Comment: @Peter ну должен сказать, что интуитивно понятней все таки размерность `(2, 100, 1024)`, но тут как вам уж хочется :)